# Error occured: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 3 When I send JSON TO WEB SERVER

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am sending JSON data to web server from android. i have array list CURRENCY_RATE_LST, and i want to send it to server.
Below is my code

Android Code:

```
    for(int i=0;i<currency_rate_lst.size();i++)
    {
        try
        {
            currency_rate_JSON .put(""+currency_code_lst.get(i), currency_rate_lst.get(i));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON ENCODIG ERROR ",""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

        final JSONObject JSON = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {
            JSON.put("currency_rate_JSON", currency_rate_JSON);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

         AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() 
            {
                String message="Nothing happend";
             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
                {

              InputStream is=null;
              String result=null;
               ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currency_rate_json",""+String.valueOf(JSON)));
              '
              '
              .
               }
```

***PHP CODE:***

```
//Receive JSON
 $JSON_Received = $_POST["currency_rate_json"]; 
 //Decode Json
 $obj = json_decode($JSON_Received, true);
  foreach ($obj['currency_rate_JSON'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;

       $currency_rate=$value;
       $currency_code=$key;

  //$con=$GLOBALS['con'];

  $sql2="UPDATE  `pirzawbh_currency_exchange`.`latest_currency_rate_table` SET currency_rate = '$currency_rate' 
  WHERE `latest_currency_rate_table`.`currency_code` ='$currency_code';";

 if (!mysql_query($sql2, $con))
 {
//echo "\n =".mysql_error($con);
  //  echo"\n errro occured";

  }
//else
    //echo"\n Updated row id = ".$rowID." Successfuly";;

 }
```

Comment: Couple issues on the php side I see. I'm not an android engineer, so I couldn't say if that side is constructing proper json or not without an example of your output.

Comment: @Randall what issues are there bro, u can tell me please

Comment: Could you add `print_r($_POST);` to the top of your php to debug what is coming in on post?

Comment: Deleted my answer because I believe I assumed wrong on your json object format. Sorry. Since I don't know android code as well, I'll step away and stop mangling your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution my self,  just change this line

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currency_rate_json",""+String.valueOf(JSON)));
```

**TO**

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currency_rate_json",""+currency_rate_JSON.toString()));
```